# Prime Factorization Java Array

Tags: java, arrays, prime-factoring

I have to write a code, that finds prime factorization of given number. The code have to give an 2-dimensional array back, that has the numbers on the first row and the powers on the second. I don't know how to save the results in this array.

```
public static long[][] primeFactorization(long l) {
    //n = 6600 = 2^3*3^1*5^2*11^1
    // z[0][4] = 2|3|5|11 - coefficient
    // z[1][4] = 3|1|2|1  - power
    int count = 0;
    int i=2;
    long[][] x = new long[2][];
    while(l%2==0) { 
        l=l/2; 
        count++; //power   8 = 2.2.2 => count = 3
     }
     i++;
     //ToDo: save i=2 in array[0][] = {2,...};
     for (i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(l); i = i+2) { 
     // While i divides l, print i and divide l 
         while (l%i == 0) { 
                int temp = i; //ToDo: save the divider in array[0][]
                count++; //ToDo: save the power in array[1][]
                l = l/i; 
                i = temp;
            } 
        } 
    return x;
}
```

Comment: "save `A` in `array[X][Y]`" simply means `array[X][Y] = A;`

Answer (score 1):

The below one is not working as expected but is in the right direction of what you are looking for. You are missing the filling array part which can be done as follows. I know the below code has some glitches which can be fixed by looking into it. But it will definitely give you a direction. If you still face issues please let us know.

```
    public static long[][] primeFactorization(long l) {
    //n = 6600 = 2^3*3^1*5^2*11^1
    // z[0][4] = 2|3|5|11 - coefficient
    // z[1][4] = 3|1|2|1  - power
    int count = 0;
    int i=2;
    long[][] x = new long[2][10];
    while(l%2==0) {
        l=l/2;
        count++; //power   8 = 2.2.2 => count = 3
    }
    x[0][0]=2;
    x[1][0]=count;
    //ToDo: save i=2 in array[0][] = {2,...};
    int row=0;
    int col=1;
    for (i = 3; i <= l; i = i+2) {
        count=0; //setting count to zero for every divisor
        // While i divides l, print i and divide l
        while (l%i == 0) {
            count++; //ToDo: save the power in array[1][]
            l = l/i;
        }
        x[row][col]=i;
        x[row+1][col]=count;
        col++;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right you receive values inside each iteration of a loop and you want to store these values in a 2d array with 2 rows. So generally you can do something like this:

1) create an integer variable outside the loop (let's say `int index = 0;`);

2) in each iteration of the loop you can save the results in your 2d array like this: `x[0][index] = result1;` and  `x[1][index] = result2`;

3)increment the variable index in the end of your loop (index++);